# How to show tooltip with dynamically changing value?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show tooltip on mouseover of textarea but value on textarea is not static.User can type in it a lengthy text and want to show that updated data in tooltip.

Any idea how to do it..?

Comment: Please post a minimal working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a Snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to **add event listener** on your textarea when user is typing and change the **title attribute** by the value of textarea.

**Working JQuery Example**

```js
$(".texttooltip").keyup(function(){
  $(this).attr("title",$(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="texttooltip"></textarea>

<textarea class="texttooltip"></textarea>

<textarea class="texttooltip"></textarea>
```

**With JS**

```js
var texttooltip = document.getElementsByClassName("texttooltip");

var updatetitle = function() { {
    this.setAttribute("title", this.value);
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < texttooltip.length; i++) {
    texttooltip[i].addEventListener('keyup', updatetitle, false);
}
```

```html
<textarea title="" class="texttooltip"></textarea>

<textarea title="" class="texttooltip"></textarea>

<textarea title="" class="texttooltip"></textarea>
```

Comment: I have multiple textarea on a page

Comment: It works for all of them, just add the same class for all of them

Comment: is dere any way to do it in javascript? Its not supported on my page.. :(